# How to set dynamic routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Lets say I have blog model, and it has a title, how would I set each blog to this signature:

```
mywebsite.com/blogs/{blog title}-{blog id}
```

Is there a recommended package to use? or shall I write my own? where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you having a url like mywebsite/blogs/id/title and for that in your routes.php have a route for blogs which accepts two parameter

```
Route::get('/blogs/{id}/{title}', 'BlogController@blog');
```

in your controller

```
public function blog($title, $id)
{
    /**  in the function parameter it is not mandatory to catch both 
    *   just take the one which is required
    */
    Blog::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
}
```

and when you want to create links dynamically in your views and then you can link to your blog by

```
<a href="/blogs/{{$array->id}}/<?php echo Str::slug($array->title);?>">{{$array->title}}</a>
```

Edited the answer just saw that you are using laravel 4

Comment: if you want it for laravel 5 everything remains the same you just need to add <?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
?>at the top of your view file

Comment: I see, I think I will stick to laravel 4, as most of the good packages are for laravel 4, what do you think?

Comment: You should keep updating yourself and your code don't stick to the same version of a framework. Laravel 5 has more magic come to the brighter side my friend

Comment: I hope I can migrate easily to laravel 5, most of the work is backends for angularJS app

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use a slash (`/`) as delimiter for `blog-title` and `blog-id`. this way, you could define your routes like the following:

```
Route::get('blogs/{title}/{id}', function($title, $id)
{
    // your code here
});
```

Call it like this: `https://yourdomain.com/blogs/yourFirstTitle/1`

Otherwise, you could explode the dash-delimited parameter you are passing by defining your route like this:

```
Route::get('blogs/{titleAndId}', function($titleAndId)
{
    $params = explode("-", $titleAndId);
    $title = $params[0];
    $id = $params[1];

    // your code here
});
```

Call it like this: `https://yourdomain.com/blogs/yourFirstTitle-1`. As you can see, this is not very readable (both, the code and the URI).

I would highly recommend the first version. Of course you should also route to controllers, but as for the routing, the examples should get you started.